# Как отправить картинку через телеграм бота не загружая ее на сервер?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь написать бота,который накладывает текст,отправленный пользователем, на картинку(картинка одна и та же). Найти способ нормально загружать картинку на сервер и отправлять ее по ссылке я так и не нашел(пытался на Google drive и Яндекс диск, картинка загружается на диск,но не отправляется). Можно ли как-то отправлять фото сразу с пк,используя путь вроде @"C"\Test/jpg" ?

Comment: добавьте к вопросу пример вашего кода

Comment: Да я согласен с @Dmitry, нужен кусок кода, который у вас не работает. Если используете "using Telegram.Bot", то это -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284958/send-photo-telegram-api вам поможет

Comment: @KuzCode Спасибо! Теперь все работает,но есть одна проблема. При открытии файла получаю ошибку System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Отказано в доступе по пути ..." Решается запуском от имени администратора,но все равно не очень удобно. Это можно как-то исправить? Папки менял,все равно ошибка

Comment: напишите отдельный вопрос для проблемы `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` и обязательно добавьте код, так быстрее получите ответ